# Div navigation bar background color not showing

Tags: css, overriding, html

So my problem is with CSS and that it seems like to me that my "background" is getting overwritten and it doesn't end up producing the background color of lightblue. Any ideas on how to fix this? Also, if all i have is the first part .nav and thats it the color shows up but once i start adding everything else it dissapears.

```
.nav{
  height : 40 px;
  background: blue;
}
.nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav ul li{
  list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML associated?

Comment: can you paste some html code

Comment: Please provide with more code.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Clearfix` for `nav` like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hyhm273v/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="nav clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS::

```
.clearfix { display: block; }

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The navigation contains floated elements so you're probably having problem with the background. To fix the issue you can use overflow:hidden or clearfix method:

```
.nav{
  height : 40 px;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
.nav{
  height : 40 px;
  background: blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

or

```
.nav:before, 
.nav:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` to your nav css:

```
.nav{
   height : 40 px;
   background: blue;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```